# DD4T .NET application

Tags: sdl-tridion, dd4t-2, sites-9

In DD4T 2.2 application, the URL value in PageController (public override ActionResult Page(string url))  is always coming as NULL. 
The RouteConfig is as below. Please suggest.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "TridionPage",
            url: "{*PageUrl}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Page" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder variable (pageUrl) in the url mask of your route must match the parameter of your action method. It will most likely work if you change the signature of your action method to:

```
 public override ActionResult Page(string pageUrl)
```

Comment: @Quirjin No, It didnt work. Event its not hitting the PageController  Page method.  For example: http://www.abc.com/ works fine, but http://www.abc.com/index.html does not.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than before. You were saying earlier that the URL was 'always coming as null', now you say that some URLs work fine. To handle URLs ending with a file extension ('.html'), add runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests="true" to the modules element inside system.webServer. See for example https://www.luminowebdesign.no/tech-blogg/asp-net-routing-and-web-config-setting-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests.

Comment: thanks a lot @Quirjin. That worked!!